# Я хочу, чтобы вложенный класс Generic в другом классе Generic определялся автоматически. Можно ли это сделать, и если да, то как?

Tags: c#, наследование, generics

Для примера у меня есть базовый класс:

```
public abstract class BaseModel<TId> : IBaseModel<TId> where TId: struct
{
    public abstract TId Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract string Path { get; set; }

    public string ToJson() => 
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

И так, мы наследуем этот класс для другого, чтобы иметь определенные поля, когда мы используем его в методе.
Пример метода ниже.

```
public class TestModel : BaseModel<int>
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public override string Path { get; set; } = "";


    // You can add your own fields to the model
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь я хочу, чтобы для каждого класса (только тех, которые унаследованы от BaseModel) работал статический метод расширения:

```
public static async Task<TObj> PutAsync<TObj, TId>(this TObj obj, string apiUrl) where TObj : BaseModel<TId> where TId : struct
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Put,
                RequestUri = new($"{apiUrl}{obj.Path}/{obj.Id}"),
                Content =
                    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TObj>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result) ??
                   default!;
        }
```

Теперь к делу, если я хочу вызвать этот метод для экземпляра класса, унаследованного от BaseModel, я делаю следующее:

```
var testModel = new TestModel();
await testModel.PutAsync<TestModel, int>("Tests");
```

Суть проблемы в том, что я не хочу указывать типы TObj и TId каждый раз, когда я вызываю метод.
Например, следующий код будет жаловаться на неопределенный тип в методе:

```
var testModel = new TestModel();
await testModel.PutAsync("Tests");
```

Comment: Так, лирическое отступление: `HttpClient` не следует создавать на каждый запрос, это может плохо кончиться, к тому же это медленно. Создавайте 1 раз `private static readonly HttpClient client`, работать будет быстрее и сокеты будут расходоваться экономнее.

Comment: Что такое `IBaseModel`? Интерфейс? Покажите его. Следом возникает вопрос, а какого типа могут быть ID?

Comment: IBaseModel такой же интерфейс как сам класс BaseModel, только без реализации самого метода. Id может быть любого "простого" типа, по типу int, byte и т.д.
На счёт HttpClient, я понимаю это, это было приведено просто как полноценная логика метода, не более.

Comment: Метод расширения - обязательно? Возможно стоит его в базовый класс перенести, тогда проблема решится сама собой. IoC контейнер или фабрики используете? И как так получается, что вы отправляете в Put объект и в ответе от сервера прилетает он же? Зачем сервер так делает?

Comment: Я думал об этом, но предполагается использовать этот же класс для получения списков, и тогда мне придётся создавать новый класс для получения списка объектов унаследованных от BaseModel, либо нарушая логику создать эти методы внутри этого же класса. Ни то ни другое делать мне не нужно, потому что это изначально нарушает цель этого класса.

Comment: На счёт возврата значения пута, повторю смысл не в логике метода, ибо это используется просто как пример. Никакой смысловой нагрузки для этого вопроса он не несёт.

Comment: С точки зрения логики, я не вижу смысла заводить обобщение ради byte айдишников. Почему бы просто не воткнуть туда long и не париться? Единственное обобщение, которое имело место бы тут быть - это string айдишник, но ваше обобщение поддерживает только struct, поэтому строка не влезает в ограничение. Отсюда вывод - делайте long айдишник и вероятность, что long.MaxValue будет превышен станет за пределами обозримого будущего. В long неявно конвертится все что угодно, в том числе и int и byte. А если сервак ваш, то можно даже в сторону Guid посмотреть в некоторых случаях.

Comment: И опять же, смысл вопроса не в этом, это не решает основной проблемы, да там в будущем ещё будет string, но это никак НЕ относится к вопросу.

Comment: Окей, ответ на ваш вопрос прост: "нет, так не получится, PutAsync не может допереть, где там у вас закопан TId, так как его нет в явном виде в аргументах." `The type arguments for method 'TestModelExtensions.PutAsync<TObj, TId>(TObj, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage.` вроде ошибка компиляции явно об этом говорит. Быть может в каком-нибудь C# 15.0 Roslyn научится раскапывать генерики, но пока он этого делать не умеет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все замечания к коду учту.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы нагородили лишнего, нет? Как я понял, вы хотите для объекта `IBaseModel<TId>` сделать метод, который получит с сервера данные в виде JSON и заполнит дальше сам себя, вернув обратно опять же, самого себя. ну тогда почему не сделать так `Task<IBaseModel<TId>> PutAsync<TId>(this IBaseModel<TId> baseModel, string apiUrl)`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у него десереализация там в конкретный тип. Так бы я примерно тоже самое посоветовал.